# Windows phone 8.1 wizard control

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to create an app that has a few setttings that need to be set before the application can continue i would like to do that using some sort of wizard. I looked at other apps and found that the 'Kid's corner' app does exactly what i want.

My question is is that a default control or is it a custom control. If it's a custom control how would one create one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific template to accomplish this task.  The most common way to do it would be to create a separate page for the wizard.  On the page you'll use various controls to actually create a settings page.  Most likely these will include Textblock (for static text), TextBox (for text entry), and ToggleSwitch for binary (e.g. On/Off) options. Here's an example of what you could use to create a very simple welcome wizard that allows the user to turn live tiles on or off.

```
<TextBlock Text="Welcome to the app!">
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" Header="Turn on live tiles?" 
              OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" 
              Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
```

If you need more info please ask :)

Reference for ToggleSwitch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868198.aspx